# Jasmine test fails when run in Chutzpah but not in browser

Tags: javascript, jasmine, chutzpah

I have a test that passes fine in the browser but is failing in Chutzpah.

Here is the portion that is failing:

```
var nameLowerCase = person.PersonName.toLowerCase();
var searchLowerCase= search.toLowerCase();
return (nameLowerCase.includes(searchLowerCase));
```

Chutzpah says:

> Message: TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'nameLowerCase.includes(searchLowerCase)') ...

It seems to have an issue with the `includes` function, because if I remove that it runs.

I will probably try replacing that functionality with Regex or something, but it's been a huge pain trying to track this down. If I am missing something stupid I would love to have that pointed out to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The JS engine which PhantomJS uses does not support the includes method yet.

Comment: Ah, so simple. I kind of considered this but then dismissed it because I just assumed the includes method would be a pretty typical thing.

Comment: It is a new feature in ES6. IE11 also does not support it.

Answer (score 0):

I still want someone else to answer this question because I want to know why `.includes` doesn't work, but using Regex solved my issue:

```
var searchPattern= new RegExp(search, 'i');
return (person.PersonName.match(searchPattern));
```